# React recursive list depth

Tags: reactjs, recursion

I have a list which renders recursively like so:

```js
  renderHeirachy(heirachy, depth) {
    const list = heirachy.map((folder, index) => {
      let subList;

      if (folder.children && folder.children.length > 0) {
        depth++;
        subList = this.renderHeirachy(folder.children, depth);
      }

      return (
        <li key={index}>
          <Link className="w100 display-block" to={`?folder=${folder.slug}`}>
            <span className="typcn typcn-folder mr1"></span>
            {folder.name}
          </Link>
          {subList}
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul className={'wbbroc-list-unstyled wbbroc-list-heirachy ' + 'test'}>
        {list}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

However the problem with this is that when I have multiple children the depth figure gets thrown out, for example:

```
ul
 li -> depth = 1
 li -> depth = 2
ul
 li -> depth = 3
```

I really just want the depth of the recursion like this:

```
ul
 li -> depth = 1
 li -> depth = 1
ul
 li -> depth = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a BFS like algorithm like: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you increment `depth` value for every child folder having children, which is not correct. The correct way is to not modify `depth` value, and pass `depth + 1` to the recursive call instead.

```
  if (folder.children && folder.children.length > 0) {
    subList = this.renderHeirachy(folder.children, depth + 1);
  }
```